# Converting a SVG image into bitmapdata in Flex 4

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, svg, flash-builder

I am working on a flex project, where I have to load a couple of SVG files and compare their pixels. To compare the pixels, I like to convert them into a byte array (BitMapData). I am able to create a bitmap data for a PNG image, but not for a SVG image. 
Can anyone help me overcome this one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get BitmapData for the SVG because it's coming in as vector data. In vector there are no pixels just geometrical primitives which describe how to render the graphics. However you can [take a snapshot of any component](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/11/16/taking-screenshots-in-flex-using-the-imagesnapshotcaptureimage-method/) in Flex which you could then compare.